# button in fixed position based on window's height

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed, sidebar

I'm trying to build a sidebar with some items (checkboxes) and a fixed button below.

The button MUST be immediately under the last checkbox (not at the bottom of the sidebar), so if I reduce the window (height) or I have full screen, the button has to still remain in the same position (so it MUST follow the height of last checkbox)

How can I build this with basic html/css without using javascript or function to calc sidebar height?

```
<div style="float: left; width: 200px; height: auto; overflow: scroll">
SIDEBAR
<p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 1</p>
<p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 2</p>
<p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 3</p>
<p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 4</p>
<p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 5</p>
<p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 6</p>
<button style="position: fixed">
GO!
</button>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 400px">
CONTENT
</div>
```

I'm trying to play with fixed height and overflow scroll.
https://jsfiddle.net/28224v2j/
As you can see if i reduce the browser window's height I can't see the button. My goal is too see the button everytime immediately under the last checkbox

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: what have you tried so far? where is your code ?

Comment: update question with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/28224v2j/1/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.side-bar {
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
}

.side-bar > .check-box-group {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.side-bar > button {
  height: 30px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-bar">
  <div class="check-box-group">
    SIDEBAR
    <p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 1</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 2</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 3</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 4</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 5</p>
    <p><input type="checkbox"/>Item 6</p>
  </div>
  <button>GO!</button>
</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
}

.sidebar p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <p>SIDEBAR</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" />Item 1</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" />Item 2</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" />Item 3</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" />Item 4</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" />Item 5</p>
  <p><input type="checkbox" />Item 6</p>
  <button>GO!</button>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>CONTENT</p>
</div>
```